# jEnvirn pointer is NULL , how to give value to this pointer in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am using JNI for java wrapper, I have initialize the jEnvirn and jObecjt as NULL.
For every function i am checking the value of these variable, whether it is null or not.

```
if (jEnvirn ==NULL || jObject ==NULL)
{
   //Some error message
}
```

when i am using Java wrapper i am getting the Value of these variables as NULL and i end up with getting error message.

Please help me out , how do these variable get value or how can assign value to these variable.

Comment: Are you trying to call Java from C++ or vice versa? You need to show more code.

Comment: yes i am using Java wrapper built on C code. For the more code i can't Tell you but for example i can tell you the flow.
I am using a function In JAVA which gets invoked through JNI in C and it calls a callback where the above if condition is implemented. So how can i get the value in jEnvirn and jObject. Are there any function for the same?

Comment: You get the environment from `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. How you get the object pointer depends on how the object is created. You don't need to post the full code - a [MCVE] is what is needed.